# PopupWindow elevation becomes distorted/darker when containing textview has ripple or selector and is clicked

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-elevation

The PopupWindow is programmatically created and its elevation is set. The shadow initially looks as expected but once a textview is clicked, whether it has ripple or selector as background the shadow changes. It looks like it animates to black or that the shadows build on top of each other.

I have tried many alternatives but still get same effect.

Testing on the emulator v21+ Lollipop. I do not have a Lollipop device to test on but I don't think it's an issue with emulator as the shadow works on other items.

The layout for the PopupWindow test_shadow.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/item_background_light"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="menuItem1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The code that inflates and sets the popupWindow:

```
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_shadow, null);
    LinearLayout menuContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.menu);

    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(menuContainer, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    float elevation = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.menuElevation);//8dp

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
        R.drawable.primary_background_light));// Shape Rect with solid color.
    popupWindow.setElevation(elevation);

    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 150, 75);
```

item_background_light:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/blueLight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_background_light"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

I must be doing something wrong or using the PopupWindow with textview incorrectly, cannot get the elevation and ripple to work together. Why does the shadow get so distorted/overdraw?

[Image of the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzMZC.jpg)

Comment: It maybe better to just ditch using popupWindow in this way and try this with a framelayout... Well it does work as expected with framelayout. Inflating framelayout and adding the elevation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the background drawable for the popupWindow has to have  corner radius value of at least one. Previously this value was left out which caused the problem.

primary_background_light:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_background_light"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
</shape>
```